# Java.lang.Character.isUnicodeIdentifierStart() equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net

Is there an equivalent method to [`Java.lang.Character.isUnicodeIdentifierStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUnicodeIdentifierStart%28char%29) in .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method directly for this.  In most .NET languages, [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can be any Unicode "letter" or an underscore, so you could easily write this as:

```
bool IsValidIdentifierStart(char ch)
{
    return ch == '_' || char.IsLetter(ch);
}
```

Note that the CLR is more flexible.  The CLS specification, chapter 8.5.1, states:

> Assemblies shall follow Annex 7 of Technical Report 15 of the Unicode Standard 3.0 governing the set of characters permitted to start and be included in identifiers, available on-line at http://www.unicode.org/unicode/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html. Identifiers shall be in the canonical format defined by Unicode Normalization Form C.

This allows the runtime to use identifiers that aren't permiitted by many of the standard languages.

Comment: That link is for VB.Net.  [This one is for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx).  What is considered a valid identifier may be different per language.  There are plenty of other languages supported by .Net that could behave differently.

Comment: Much appreciated Reed.

Comment: Note that the '@' character is also a valid starting identifier character in c#. See [Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @AtinSkrita Actually, `@` is not a valid identifier in C# - it's used to allow identifiers to share language keywords, but the actual identifier doesn't have the `@` character.

Comment: @AtinSkrita From that link: ". The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix."

Comment: @Reed I did not say it was a valid identifier. You are right, the `@` character is used to disambiguate keywords from identifiers, and it is therefore not included in the actual identifier. However, it is a valid starting character(or prefix) for an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Char.IsLetter() as a Unicode Identifier must start with an alphabetical letter...

EDIT:
IsLetter() would return true for an underscore, which is invalid, so that should also be checked for.

Comment: Not true in .NET - Identifiers can also start with an underscore, which would not work for `IsLetter`.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: There is not a language called ".NET".

Comment: @Jason True - Was referring more to the CLR, and most "common" languages targeting the CLS, as a whole there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than `ch == '_' || char.IsLetter(ch)` suggested by Reed Copsey than check out 
[Char.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz49h034%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which give you detailed Unicode categorization of a character.